# What is the solution of equation $(z - 2002)^{2002} = \bar{z} - 2002$ in $\mathbb{C}$ numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have an equation $$\left(z - 2002\right)^{2002} = \bar{z} - 2002.$$ My question is - what are the solutions of that equation.

*My attempt:* Polar form of $z$, which is $z = \left|z\right| \left(\cos(\varphi) + i \cdot \sin(\varphi)\right)$, and I know the polar form for $\bar{z} = \left|z\right|\left(\cos(\varphi) - i \cdot \sin(\varphi)\right)$, but here it ends... What is the next step?

Comment: Observe that $\overline{z}-2002 = \overline{z}-\overline{2002} = \overline{z-2002}$.

Comment: ...and don't overlook the $2004^{th}$ solution.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

put $$Z=z-2002=re^{it}$$

the equation becomes

$$r^{2002}e^{i2002t}=re^{-it}$$
or

$$r^{2001}e^{i2003t}=e^{i2k\pi}$$

So
$$r^{2001}=1=r \text{ and } t=\frac{2k\pi}{2003}$$

thus
$$z=Z+2002=2002+e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{2003}}$$
with
$$k=0,1,2,...,2002$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you take conjugate of equation and multiply it with original equation, you get $$|z-2002|=1$$
So,
let $z-2002=a=e^{i\theta}$.
Then we have, $$a^{2002}=\bar a$$
So, $$e^{{2002} {i\theta}}=e^{-i\theta}$$
So, $$e^{2003i\theta}=1$$
So, $$\theta =\frac {2k\pi}{2003}$$ where $0\leq k\leq 2002$.
So, $$z=2002+e^{i\theta}$$ gives you all possible $2003$ solutions.